# 1с как выполнить команду после отрисовки управляемой формы

Tags: 1с

Хочу отобразить индикатор загрузки
пробовал разные варианты , но не выходит
Вариант 1

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПриОткрытии(Отказ)
    Картинка = БиблиотекаКартинок.Загрузка;
    Погнали(ФормаДляОткрытия,ВходящийИНН)//Это долгая процедура
    Закрыть();
КонецПроцедуры
```

Форма даже не отображается.
Пробовал помещать в:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПередЗакрытием(Отказ, СтандартнаяОбработка)
    Погнали(ФормаДляОткрытия,ВходящийИНН);
КонецПроцедуры
```

результат тот же , формы не видно , просто стандартный курсов загрузки.

Как сделать так чтобы форма отобразилась, а потом началась эта долгая процедура ?

Comment: Индикатор загрузки чего?

Comment: Индикатор загрузки формы

Comment: ты про индикатор, который отображает какую-либо длительную операцию? Просто сама форма грузится молниеносно.

Comment: Форма не отображается - как сделать что бы она отображалась во время работы долгой процедуры и есть вопрос.
В процедуре Приоткрытиии() есть долго выполняемая процедура
Погнали(ФормаДляОткрытия,ВходящийИНН)//Это долгая процедура.
Чтобы пользователь, когда смотрел на замершую 1С ,  мог определить , что программа продолжает работать , я хочу сделать какаю либо анимацию. В данном случае анимация расположена на этой форме.

Comment: У Вас типовая конфигурация или сами с нуля пишите?

Comment: Дописанная УПП 1.3

Answer (score 0):

То что вы хотите сделать - это длительная операция, тобишь фоновое задание. При открытии формы запускается фоновое задание, а форма, через обработчик ожидания, проверяет данные фонового задания. Если вы запустите с формы в этом же потоке долгую процедуру - 1С просто зависнет выполняя процедуру

Comment: как-то не очень похоже, что это ответ на вопрос «Как сделать так чтобы форма отобразилась, а потом началась эта долгая процедура ?». если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, свой ответ.

Comment: Автору необходима индикация при выполнении долгой процедуры. Если он сделает выполнение в одном потоке - будет зависание. Если через фоновое задание и опрашивание - будет индикация, которая ему и нужна